# Unable to execute JasperReports: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

Trying to execute JasperReports 6.3.1 simple report from Eclipse:

```
package test.jaspertest;

import java.util.HashMap;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;

public class JasperTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");

        try {
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("reports/simple.xml");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                jasperReport,
                new HashMap(),
                new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "reports/simple.pdf");
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Have this out message:

```
Apr 11, 2017 1:59:41 PM net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry loadRegistries
WARNING: Extension resource jar:file:/C:/Portable%20Programs/eclipse/packages/jasperreports/dist/jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.1.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties was found to be a duplicate of jar:file:/C:/Portable%20Programs/eclipse/packages/jasperreports/dist/jasperreports-6.3.1.jar!/jasperreports_extension.properties in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93
Start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:150)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:503)
    at test.jaspertest.JasperTest.main(JasperTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Java version 1.8.0.121. I'm not very familiar with Java so please can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the `itext-2.1.7.jar` in your classpath. add it and the error will go away.
The `itext.jar` is a dependecy which is needed by jarperReport